# How to deal with the poles in imaginary axis when applying Matsubara Sums?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

The start point of Matsubara Sums is:
$$\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{\omega_n}F(i\omega_n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C dz F(z)n(z)$$
where $n(z)$ is the bosonic/fermionic distribution function with the pole $z=i\omega_n$, and the loop $C$ circles the imaginary axis (see Fig. a). Next step, we can change the loop as $C'$ which circles poles of $F(z)$ (see Fig. b and c).

[image]

**However, from my point of view, there exists an constraint for the start point: there is no poles of $F(z)$ in the imaginary axis; otherwise,  loop $C$ also circles the poles of $F(z)$. How to deal with such problem?** Or, welcome to good reference. Thanks!

For example, $F(z)=\frac{1}{-z^2+\omega_k^2}$ with the pole $z=\pm\omega_k$, how about $\omega_{k_0}=0$, which locates in the imaginary axis. Or, $F(z)=-\frac{1}{i v_{n}+z-\epsilon_{\mathbf{p}}}$, with the pole $z=\epsilon_p-i v_{n}$, how about $\epsilon_p=0$, which also locates in the imaginary axis.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you think the procedure doesn't work if $F$ has poles in the imaginary axis?

Comment: @JohnDonne Yes, and I also think this is a general situation？

Comment: I'm probably wrong, but can't you just remove the contribution from those poles (assuming the function is nice enough and there are finitely many poles) using the residue theorem?